# How can I make values inserted next to the importrange follow if there is a line insertion

Tags: google-sheets

In column A8 I have an importrange, which takes the values from A1:A4, in column B I have values that I insert manually:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMsr1.png)

but I would like these values from column B to follow the insertion of the importrange line:
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry9IE.png)

This is just an example, I intend to do this in another larger spreadsheet in which I do not have access to the data, because the data is blocked, as someone else is responsible for filling it in.

If there is a way to do this with AppScript, onEdit or something like that, I would appreciate it.